# SQL IsNumeric(), shouldn't it return a bit?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm just curious to know why SQL IsNumeric() returns **int** instead of **bit**?  Seems like it should return a **bit**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `bit` data type was added comparatively recently in the evolution of Transact-SQL. You will find that a lot of system functions were at least designed, if not added, before `bit` was added. I have noticed that quite a few system procedures added since then do take `bit` parameters where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Hm, yes, I agree with you, it would be more logical if it would return a bit. But in the end, it doesn't matter, does it?